# Pinterest style grid layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of items that are different heights (same width), and I'm trying to implement a responsive style grid that will handle the height difference on the items. When a component is tapped on, it'll grow taller to show more information.

I'm using this library right now: https://github.com/xudafeng/autoresponsive-react-native but it requires fixed width and heights, but on some of these items, there is just no way to know how tall they are going to be before they are rendered.

Is there another library that might do what I need, or something I can do to make this current one work?

I've tried quite a few things, but it's always updating the information I need one step behind (ex. Height will be 70, I have nothing, tapped element is 250, I have 70, ...).

Comment: http://dantrain.github.io/react-stonecutter/

Comment: That doesn't look like it supports React Native

Comment: also have this kind of problem, especially cause i want to solve it with react native's Listview, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316531/react-native-listview-grid-layout-with-listview-elements-that-align-and-append-i  

have you found a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @manpenaloza: I never did find a good solution, so I ended up changing the view to something else.

Comment: This article is very helpful:  https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-create-a-masonry-layout-component-using-react-f30ec9ca5e99

Answer (score 0):

You should use [this component](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid). There is [a post about it](https://blog.nativebase.io/dead-simple-layouts-with-react-native-2c611b0be8b1#.4ym2dmm63).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm looking at the docs now, but it doesn't look like it supports what I'm going for?